# Ajuda para resolver duas questões Javascript

Tags: javascript, funções, matemática

Olá, não estou conseguindo resolver essas duas questões, poderam me ajudar.

```
function dobroDoNumero (){
  var dobroA = 4+4;
  var dobroB = 7+7;
  var dobroC = 8+-8;
  var resultado = dobroA+ ', ' +dobroB+ ', ' +dobroC
  return resultado
}
```

```
function metade(){
  var num1 = 4/2;
  var num2 = 60/2;
  var num3 = 30/2;
  var resultado = num1+ ', ' +num2+ ', ' +num3;
  return resultado
  console.log(resultado)
}
```

Obrigada :)

Comment: Qual é o problema do primeiro código?

Comment: Evite o cossole.log depois do return: `function metade(){
  var num1 = 4/2;
  var num2 = 60/2;
  var num3 = 30/2;
  var resultado = num1+ ', ' +num2+ ', ' +num3; console.log(resultado)

  return resultado
  }`

Comment: Explica melhor qual é o problema com os códigos

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

No primeiro código tem um erro que é mostrando no console: `8,14,0`.

O erro está na quarta linha: `var dobroC = 8+-8;`

Solução:

```js
function dobroDoNumero(){
  var dobroA = 4*2;
  var dobroB = 7*2;
  var dobroC = 8*2;
  var resultado = dobroA+ ', ' +dobroB+ ', ' +dobroC;
  return resultado;
}
console.log(dobroDoNumero());
// 8, 14, 16
```

No segundo código,o erro está na chamada do `console.log(resultado)` depois da chamada do `return resultado;`.

Solução:

```js
function metade(){
  var num1 = 4/2;
  var num2 = 60/2;
  var num3 = 30/2;
  var resultado = num1+ ', ' +num2+ ', ' +num3;
  console.log(resultado);
// 2, 30, 15
  return resultado;
}
metade()
```

Espero ter ajudado.